# Add Cocoa Touch Framework target - product is not created

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, xcode6

For existing project that I have, I would like to add Cocoa Touch Framework target, to bind all the code in one package and later use it in another project.

I've succeeded creating and using standard Cocoa Touch Framework (created framework, added custom classes with function, built a framework product, dragged it to test project , imported my public headers and was able to use the functions)

Now I am trying to create the real thing. It is a bit different. The framework is not created from scratch. I have to use already existing classes of a project.
So I have added a new Cocoa Touch Framework target to the project. I am building the target but the framework product is not created. Why???

Answer (score 0):

The framework was actually created. Strangely though the it was marked red in xCode in the products section, so I thought there was some problem. But it was found in the derived data folder.